# Tsung. How to continue use the previous Jabber session after HTTP switching to and back?

Tags: tsung

I'm trying to create load testing scenario with tsung. I need to use 2 types of session: ts_jabber and ts_http. May I continue use Jabber session after HTTP switching to and back?
This is my code:

```
<sessions>
   <session probability="100" name="session1" type="ts_http">
     //some code
   <change_type  new_type="ts_jabber" host="*****" port="5222" server_type="tcp" store = "true"/>

   <request subst="true">
         <jabber type="connect" ack="local">
             <xmpp_authenticate username="%%_loginForChat%%" passwd="%%_password%%"/>
         </jabber>
   </request>

   <thinktime value="10"></thinktime>

   <transaction name="authenticate">
     <request>
        <jabber type="auth_sasl" ack="local"></jabber></request>
     <request>
        <jabber type="connect" ack="local"></jabber> </request>
     <request>
        <jabber type="auth_sasl_bind" ack="local" ></jabber></request>
     <request>
        <jabber type="auth_sasl_session" ack="local" ></jabber></request>
   </transaction>

   <change_type new_type="ts_http" host="******" port="80" server_type="tcp"
       //some code
   <change_type  new_type="ts_jabber" host="*******" port="5222" server_type="tcp"  />

   <request subst="true">
        <jabber type="muc:join" ack="local" room="%%_app_id%%_%%_groupChat_room_id%%"              nick="%%_loginForChat%%"/>
   </request>

</session>
```

After run this code i get an error: "Error: Unknown msg {tcp_closed, #Port<0.1183>} receive in state wait_ack, stop"
Help me, please.